# ion-datetime continuous minutes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using ion-datetime for a simple time picker with hours and minutes:

```
<ion-item> 
         <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
         <ion-datetime 
            display-format="HH:mm" 
            picker-format="HH:mm" 
            [(ngModel)]="time"
         </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

Is there any way to have the minutes continue/restart at 00, so that the user can continue scrolling down instead of having to scroll all the way to the top? I.e.

[image]